# Is there a foolproof way to check browser in JS or Node.JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, browser, cross-browser

I have a website where I want to ban all users not using a chrome and derivatives, firefox and derivatives, safari, or a new version of opera (IE and other old browsers may compromise security). Is there an absolutely foolproof way (so that even a hacker couldn't spoof their browser) to do this in JavaScript on the client or server side?

Comment: make sure your server is hardened. that is the only defense. you can't control any client.

Comment: The answer is "no"

Comment: If a specific *browser* can compromise security of your website, then you won't gain that security back even if you ban it. It suggests the flaw is within easy reach of the users which, in turn, means that anybody will be able to exploit it, even if they use an "approved" browser. This sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: Well, the issue is that old IE versions don't support cookie security (specifically httpOnly), which I have no idea how to work around.

Comment: @IsaacKrementsov - Unless you allow 3rd party, malicious and untrusted Javascript from external sources into your web page, you're under a bit of a misconception about what httpOnly buys you.  If the cookies are protected by https while in transit, then the only way they get captured out of the user's browser is if there's a malicious tool running on the user's computer.  And, if they have such a tool running, then the cookies can be taken from the browser storage anyway.  What kind of attack are you worried about that you think you have to have `httpOnly` in order to be safe?

Answer (score 0):

No, it can't be done reliably. You could use some complex JavaScript timing runs and compare the time to execute for the bank of tests against the known timings for each browser and version. Obviously this would have to be tested on a ratio basis to rule out differences in hardware performance. This would not, however, be foolproof and would require "fingerprinting" performance for every single browser version and make that you will accept and would need to be constantly updated as each new browser version was released. This is not a foolproof method and is generally considered a very bad idea. It can also result in false positives which will cause people with compliant browsers to be denied access based on variability in your JavaScript fingerprinting tests.

Hardening your server is a much better way to go and using simple browser identifiers like navigator name will provide the results you need. The trouble with trying to design a foolproof method is that, even if you get it to work, a cagey hacker can still get you. Hardening the Server is the only real way to secure your site.

Comment: And I can just load it up Fiddler/Charles and see what is sent back and put that on my request.... That is not going to make any difference.

Comment: The issue is with cookies, not the actual server-side code. I want to make cookies only readable by the server (while it is hard to read cookies as is, this would make the security bulletproof unless a hacker gained access to my server).

Answer (score 0):

**This is a terrible security method**

You should not be banking on the fact that a user is visiting your site from a particular browser. You should instead choose to either allow functionality to those compliant browsers and disable it to others via signatures (the part the browser sends which helps identify the particular browser type).

Most importantly, you should **never leave a vulnerability in your application!** If you know it's a vulnerability in different browser types, fix the problem - don't try to hide it. People will always find a way around a hidden problem. Easy fix? Make it so there is no problem to hide!